# Run app script if cell in specific sheet changes value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to run this script automatically whenever the value in cell A1 in sheet "NETRankingsRohdaten" changes. Thanks for help.

```
function NETsaveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var reportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NETRankingsRohdaten");
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NETDatabase")
  var NETsaveData = reportSheet.getRange("A2:F")
                              .getValues();
  var lastRow = recordsSheet.getLastRow();
  //copy data
  recordsSheet.getRange(lastRow+ 1, 1, NETsaveData.length, 6)
              .setValues(NETsaveData);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to run the script when the cell "A1" of "NETRankingsRohdaten" sheet is edited.
  In this case, how about using OnEdit trigger? When OnEdit trigger is used, your script becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var reportSheet = range.getSheet();
  if (reportSheet.getSheetName() != "NETRankingsRohdaten" || range.rowStart != 1 || range.columnStart != 1) return;
  var ss = e.source;
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NETDatabase")
  var NETsaveData = reportSheet.getRange("A2:F").getValues();
  var lastRow = recordsSheet.getLastRow();
  recordsSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, NETsaveData.length, 6).setValues(NETsaveData);
}
```

- In this case, when the cell "A1" of "NETRankingsRohdaten" sheet is edited, the script is run. So, when you directly run this function, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- If you want to use `NETsaveData()`, you can also use the following script. In this case, your `NETsaveData()` is not modified. But when the cell "A1" of "NETRankingsRohdaten" sheet is edited, the script is run.

  ```
    function onEdit(e) {
      var range = e.range;
      var reportSheet = range.getSheet();
      if (reportSheet.getSheetName() != "NETRankingsRohdaten" || range.rowStart != 1 || range.columnStart != 1) return;
      NETsaveData();
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The modified script does exactly what I was looking for. It's not clear to me what the second script does :-) But thanks alo lot for your help!

Comment: @user3392296 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the additional script in "Note" section, in this case, when the cell "A1" of "NETRankingsRohdaten" sheet is edited, your function `NETsaveData()` is run. I thought that you might have wanted to use `NETsaveData()` as the individual function. But from your replying, I could understand that my 1st script was useful. I'm glad about it. Thank you, too.

Comment: Sorry, I see that it seems if cell A1 ist filled with new data by =query(importrange the script is not running.

Comment: I believe onEdit is triggered only if the user types something from the keyboard or uses the mouse.  It does not respond to functions changing a cell value.

Comment: @user3392296 I think that TheWizEd's comment is the answer for your new question.